# Load a second URL from a JSON response, without affecting the initial JSON binding in iOS

Tags: ios, objective-c, json, uitableview

I am working on a native iOS application that uses JSON binding. One of the data in the JSON response(along with data like Name, Price, Location etc) is "imageURL". This is basically another URL that returns a `UIImage`. I need to display all of this in a `UITableView`. As you can imagine, a call to the `imageURL` slows down the app ridiculously. I tried to work with threads but didn't do much good.
What is the most efficient way to do this?

Comment: try afnetworking and For image, sdimageview

Answer (score 0):

You can try to load image lazily when cell is on screen and cached the imaged loaded using [NSCache](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/NSCache_Class/) or 3rd party library like [SDWebImage](https://github.com/rs/SDWebImage) for later usage.